# Pylons 1.0 - c.id no longer being automatically set on python v2.6.2 and 2.7

Tags: python, pylons, paster

I am at a loss on this one, I intalled a SSD on my dev box today and started with a fresh development environment.

In short, pylons no longer sets the c.id based on the id passed to the action.

Code, error, and libs install: http://pastie.org/1064929

Very strange, because my production server is mirroring my python version (2.6.2) and all my python libs are at the latest release on both machines. I only experience this on my dev machine. I have tried python 2.7 with the same results.

Python 2.6.2 (r262:71600, Apr 16 2009, 09:17:39))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after trying older releases of paste and routes I gave up and removed all usage of c.id. I suppose that is what I get for relying on too much magic.